# Is it possible to use a strcpy inside a scanf or a sscanf? (in C language)

Tags: c

I read somewhere that when we use structs we can't just write something like «`example1.name = "Jim";`», instead of it we should write «`strcpy(example1.name, "Jim");`»

The thing is that I need to use a struct and I need to scanf (and right after that sscanf) some information that corresponds to a string and I don't know how I should do it.

Could somebody help me, please?

**Edit:**

My code isn't complete and I know it's wrong, but I'll post it here so that you know what I am talking about:

```c
int main(){

    struct Cards{
        int value;
        char type[4];
    };

    for(i=1, 0 < i && i < 11, i++){  
         struct Cards cardi;
    }

    scanf("%d %s", &cardi.value, cardi.type); 
/*at this point I just know it's wrong but I am really bugged.
  I thought about something like «scanf("%d %s", &cardi.value, strcpy(cardi.type, "%s"));»
  but I just know it's very wrong */ 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Formatting tip: use back ticks to format code: `\`code here\``

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "`strcpy()` inside `scanf()`". Please provide a code snippet of what you want to try and we will be happy to explain.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my question then! Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true only about structs, but for all strings. You can use `=` for strings, only when you initialize them. You can scanf a string and place it in a string. Example:

```
scanf("%s", my_struct.str);
```

If you already have a string and you want to pass it in a struct, or in an other string variable you then need strcpy:

```
char str1[] = "abc", str2[4];
strcpy(str2, str1);
```

or

```
strcpy(my_struct.str, str1);
```

Edit:

```
for(i=1, 0 < i && i < 11, i++) {
    struct Cards cardi;
}
```

In your code cardi is not card0, card1 etc, it is a struct Cards variable with the name cardi.

If you want to store 10 cards, you sould make an array of struct Cards with capacity of 10 like:

```
struct Cards array[10];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d %s", &array[i].value, array[i].type);
}
```

Anyway i suggest that you focus on learning the basics on arrays, strings and pointers before you use structs.

Edit 2: You don't want to define structs inside your main, because in that way, if you write a function it will not "see" your struct. Structs usually are written in the top of the code.

Comment: Ohh okay, I had no idea about that! But I think I need to use structs in this (at least I see no other options) because the point of the program is to receive a bunch of strings representing cards (for example «4D 5D 7S AH AD» (where 4D is four of diamonds and etc) and analyse the existence of pairs, full houses, etc (because the game I'm analyzing is poker) and return the winner. Do you recommend an easiest way of doing it? Thank you :)

Comment: Well, if you want to scan the cards in this format like <number><Letter> (where number and letter are one character) you could just scan a string of 2 characters and then extract what you need: 

`scanf("%2s", tmp);`

`card.type = tmp[0]; /*This way type is a character, not an int*/`

`card.color = tmp[1];` 

I just want to say, that you sould be focusing on simpler programs so that you learn the basics that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `scanf()` is correct.  However scanning strings using `%s` is dangerous and discouraged.  This is because the `type` member of your structure has space for only 4 characters, including the terminating `'\0'` (NUL) character.  Entering a string longer than 3 characters will result in the extra characters being written into an unknown area of memory likely corrupting other variables and leading to incorrect program execution or a program crash.  You can correct this by adding a string length limit, simply replace `%s` with `%3s`, where 3 is the maximum numbers of characters that will be accepted (`scanf` will automatically add a `'\0'` (NUL) character following the last scanned character).

Below are some additional comments:

If you want to declare an array for 10 Cards, you could do it this way without any loops:

```c
    struct Cards cardi[10];
```

To scan values into the first card (C arrays are 0-based):

```c
    // this will scan into the first card; type field is restricted to at most 3 characters
    scanf("%d %3s", &cardi[0].value, cardi[0].type);
```

At the top of the file you'll want to add:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

This header file provides a prototype (declaration) for the `scanf` function (among many others).